# How to change jquery datepicker's parent div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have jquery ui datepicker inside the slider which is working on mouseover/leave and each time i try to pick a date it register mouseleave event because datepicker has been appended to the bottom of the page and its not in the div which is firing hover events. So i need to change datepicker's target div... any idea how? 
[open the info & pricing bar, click book now and then try to pick a date](http://www.bozioko.com/en/room/levandule)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok... i did a search inside jqueryui-custom file for "body" and i 've replaced it with "#mainmenu" which is the id of the div where i want it to be.

Comment: Looks like I'll be doing the same. -_-